# How to auto rotate page when printing NSDocument via NSView?

Tags: cocoa, printing

I have a NSDocument descendant that I would like to print to a single page - stretched to fit and auto rotated when the page is wider than high.
The rendering view determines its bounds based on the content. 
rectForPage simply returns [self bounds];
knowsPageRange sets range.length = 1 and range.location = 1 and returns YES.
Printing is done using the code below.

Everything works, execpt the auto -rotation. In the Print Panel I see the preview in the correct shape (wider than high, the correct size etc.), However when I then print, the page is fitted, but in portrait mode, unnecessary scaling down the image.
If I do not set printInfo.paperSize, it auto rotates OK, but does not scale, instead it clips the image. Any idea?

Additional info: The "View PDF" from the print panel shows the page OK in Preview.
Printing from Preview, then shows the image *rotated* in Preview's Print Panel to match the paper potrait orientation (that is: the landscape image itself appears rotated). This is different from my case where it shows unrotated in the print panel. Printing from Preview's Print Panel then does the correct thing.

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)printSettings error:(NSError **)outError {
    MindMapRenderingView *renderingView = [[MindMapRenderingView alloc] initWithMindMap:_mindMap 
                                                                          printJobTitle:[_mindMap singleLineTitle]];
    NSSize pageSize = [renderingView bounds].size;
    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:renderingView
                                                                      printInfo:[self printInfo]];
    [renderingView release];

    NSPrintInfo* printInfo = [printOperation printInfo];
    [[printInfo dictionary] addEntriesFromDictionary:printSettings];

    if (isLandscape)
        [printInfo setOrientation:NSLandscapeOrientation];
    else
        [printInfo setOrientation:NSPortraitOrientation];

    [printInfo setPaperSize:pageSize];

    [printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];

    return printOperation;
}
```

Comment: could it be your printer trying to be smarter than you?  what happens when you "print to PDF"?  Does it still come out with incorrect orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Have not found a way to auto rotate, but after more experimenting I came up with the solution that mimics the way Preview prints the landscape pdf: I rotate the frame for the NSView that is used to draw the output. In drawRect: I also draw the output rotated using NSAffineTransform. That gives the required result. Only drawback is that using "View PDF" from the print panel now shows the pdf rotated too.